# Is there a way to send an email including a csv of all the entityform submissions?

Tags: entities, emails

Is there a way to set Drupal up to send an email with an attachment of all of the entityform submissions for a specific form after each time the form is submitted?

Comment: Seems like there is no readily available site-building solution for this. Would you be fine with a custom/coded suggestion?